# What Dominion Cards use victory tokens?

Tags: dominion

I'm aware of three cards in Dominion: Prosperity that use victory tokens and have seen some in Dominion Empires as well. In a definitive list, what cards utilize victory tokens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is, at [The Dominion Strategy Wiki](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Victory_token).

Cards:
Chariot Race, Farmers' Market, Bishop, Crumbling Castle, Monument, Sacrifice, Temple, Emporium, Groundskeeper, Plunder, Wild Hunt, Goons, Grand Castle

Events:
Conquest, Wedding, Triumph, Salt the Earth, Ritual, Dominate

Landmarks: Aqueduct, Arena, Basilica, Baths, Battlefield, Colonnade, Defiled Shrine, Labyrinth, Mountain Pass, Tomb